# Semantic similarity using Wordnet in Python

Tags: python, semantics, similarity, wordnet

'toy_data.csv'

[image]

Hi, all,
I am new to Python and currently building the Python code to extract a semantic similarity using Wordnet in Python. I have the following code to extract the semantic similarity, but the code is for only two words (e.g., dog, cat).

```
from sematch.semantic.similarity import WordNetSimilarity
wns = WordNetSimilarity()

# Computing English word similarity using Li method
wns.word_similarity('dog', 'cat', 'li') # 0.449327301063
print(dog.path_similarity(cat))
```

What I want to do is I want to get the semantic similarity between two words in the toy data set that I attached here (all the combinations between tword* and iword*) and add these numbers.

Using the example data that I attached, 1) first, I would like to get the semantic similarities of the following word pairs from (1) to (6) (see below 'All the combinations between tword* and iword*'), 2) add the column that contains the sum of the semantic similarities (i.e.(1)+(2)+(3)+(4)+(5)+(6)) at the end of the data set (i.e., the next to 'iword2' in this example), and 3) save the result including the sum column to my local laptop.

- All the combinations between tword* and iword*

(1) tword1 and iword1 / (2) tword1 and iword2 / (3) tword2 and iword1 / (4) tword2 and iword2 / (5) tword3 and iword1 / (6) tword3 and iword2

Say the name of the toy data that I attached is 'toy_data.csv' and the output data is 'toy_output.csv', can someone offer the Python code to solve this problem? Many thanks, in advance.